# Rubymine debugger slow

Tags: rubymine

Rubymine 7.1 (build RM# 141.644) debugger on a rails 4.1.10 project is very slow. Rendering pages takes +12 seconds.

I've tried setting my JVM properties as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/tuning-rubymine.html#d219602e110) but its still super slow. Here are my settings:

```
cat rubymine.vmoptions
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Any other suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slightly experimental release for OSX Yosemite that is quite a bit faster.

They say, "This alternative RubyMine 7.1 distribution bundles JDK 1.8 customized by the JetBrains team for better performance. Please note this non-default option may contain some issues."

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/